# Можно ли сделать, что запрос "SELECT _WHERE _AND_IN" выбрал все записи?

Tags: mysql, запрос, select

Имеется запрос, который выбирает записи по двум критериям и по списку значений

```
SELECT * FROM tst_014_01_test WHERE name_camp = 'camp_1' AND ctrg_ur_1 IN (crit_2)
```

составляющие запроса:
- name_camp;
- camp_1;
- ctrg_ur_1;
- crit_2 = ('ctrg_ur_1_1', 'ctrg_ur_1_2');
являются переменными из кода

Можно ли как-то сделать чтобы он выбрал все значения?
Что-то в духе:

```
SELECT * FROM tst_014_01_test WHERE name_camp = 'camp_1' AND ctrg_ur_1 IN (*)
```

Только как сделать правильно?

**СУТЬ ПРОБЛЕМЫ**
1. Пользователь. Вводит в ТекстБокс список значений **ctrg_ur_1_1**, **ctrg_ur_1_2**;
2. Программа. ТекстБокс -> "переменная" (crit_2 = 'ctrg_ur_1_1', 'ctrg_ur_1_2');
3. Программа. "Переменная" - > "Запрос" ;

Т.е. два сценария:
   - вар. 1. выборочный - выбираются все значения по **списку**;
   - вар. 2. ВСЁ -  выбираются все значения;

Т.е. для вариант **вар.1** нужен **запрос 1** (Запрос с "IN"), а для запроса **вар.2** нужен вариант **запрос 2** (Запрос без "IN")

Не хочется в программе клиента лепить второй блок для обработки "вар. 2" через отдельный запрос...  Хотелось бы решить всё одним запросом, который подойдёт для обоих случаев.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tst_014_01_test WHERE name_camp = 'camp_1'` не ?

Comment: Видимо вопрос не совсем правильно сформулирован `AND ctrg_ur_1 IN (*)` не имеет смысла.

Comment: Может быть AND ctrg_ur_1 IS NOT NULL ?

Comment: @ArchDemon дополнил вопрос

Comment: @Дмитрий Гвоздь дополнил вопрос

Comment: Два запроса не надо делать. собирайте в переменной текст запроса сначала без IN. А если фильтры того требуют добавляйте " AND ... IN()". Все равно у вас переменная перечислимая и вы либо ее целиком помещаете в текст, либо делаете из нее массив и в запрос пишите нужное количество плейсхолдеров, так что текст все равно правите

Comment: @Mike Сделал `SELECT * FROM " + zpr_tbl_name + " WHERE " + pole_1 + " = '" + crit_1 + "' " + var_zpr_AND_IN;`, где  `var_zpr_AND_IN` = `AND ctrg_ur_1 IN (crit_2)` - переменная; Ваш ответ верен. Всё работает

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя ли использовать подзапрос , что то вроде
SELECT * FROM tst_014_01_test WHERE name_camp = 'camp_1' AND ctrg_ur_1 IN (SELECT ctrg_ur_1 .... ), если так хочется использовать IN

Comment: дополнил вопрос